# Error Found while training Bert Uncased Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am facing issue with Bert while training the model.
I am using the bert-base-uncased model for training. The error says there is string passed into the dropout layer rather than tensor, however I am passing in Tensor as an input to the model.
Please find the attached error:

```
 in <module>:49                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   46 │   │   if accuracy>best_accuracy:                                                          │
│   47 │   │   │   best_accuracy=accuracy                                                          │
│   48 │   │   │   torch.save(model.state_dict(),CFG.MODEL_PATH)                                   │
│ ❱ 49 train()                                                                                     │
│   50                                                                                             │
│   51                                                                                             │
│   52                                                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ in train:41                                                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│   38 │                                                                                           │
│   39 │   best_accuracy=0                                                                         │
│   40 │   for epoch in range(CFG.EPOCHS):                                                         │
│ ❱ 41 │   │   train_fn(train_loader,model,optimizer,device,scheduler)                             │
│   42 │   │   outputs,targets= eval_fn(val_loader,model,device)                                   │
│   43 │   │   outputs= np.array(outputs)>=0.5                                                     │
│   44 │   │   accuracy= metrics.accuracy_score(targets,outputs)                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│ in train_fn:20                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   17 │   │   targets= targets.to(device,dtype=torch.float)                                       │
│   18 │   │                                                                                       │
│   19 │   │   optimizer.zero_grad()                                                               │
│ ❱ 20 │   │   outputs= model(ids=ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, mask=mask)                   │
│   21 │   │   loss= loss_fn(outputs,targets)                                                      │
│   22 │   │   loss.backward()                                                                     │
│   23 │   │   optimizer.step()                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py:153 in forward        │
│                                                                                                  │
│   150 │   def forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs):                                                  │
│   151 │   │   with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function("DataParallel.forward"):              │
│   152 │   │   │   if not self.device_ids:                                                        │
│ ❱ 153 │   │   │   │   return self.module(*inputs, **kwargs)                                      │
│   154 │   │   │                                                                                  │
│   155 │   │   │   for t in chain(self.module.parameters(), self.module.buffers()):               │
│   156 │   │   │   │   if t.device != self.src_device_obj:                                        │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ in forward:11                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│    8 │                                                                                           │
│    9 │   def forward(self,ids,mask,token_type_ids):                                              │
│   10 │   │   _,o2= self.bert(ids,attention_mask=mask,token_type_ids=token_type_ids)              │
│ ❱ 11 │   │   bo= self.bert_drop(o2)                                                              │
│   12 │   │   output= self.out(bo)                                                                │
│   13 │   │   return output                                                                       │
│   14                                                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/dropout.py:59 in forward                │
│                                                                                                  │
│    56 │   """                                                                                    │
│    57 │                                                                                          │
│    58 │   def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:                                            │
│ ❱  59 │   │   return F.dropout(input, self.p, self.training, self.inplace)                       │
│    60                                                                                            │
│    61                                                                                            │
│    62 class Dropout1d(_DropoutNd):                                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1252 in dropout                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1249 │   │   return handle_torch_function(dropout, (input,), input, p=p, training=training, i  │
│   1250 │   if p < 0.0 or p > 1.0:                                                                │
│   1251 │   │   raise ValueError("dropout probability has to be between 0 and 1, " "but got {}".  │
│ ❱ 1252 │   return _VF.dropout_(input, p, training) if inplace else _VF.dropout(input, p, traini  │
│   1253                                                                                           │
│   1254                                                                                           │
│   1255 def alpha_dropout(input: Tensor, p: float = 0.5, training: bool = False, inplace: bool =  │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
TypeError: dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str
```

Please also find the attached Model Class and trainer functions.

```
class BertDataset:
    def __init__(self,review,target):
        self.review=review
        self.target=target
        
        self.tokenizer= CFG.TOKENIZER
        self.max_len= CFG.MAX_LEN
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.review)
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        review= str(self.review[idx])
        review= " ".join(review.split())
        inputs= self.tokenizer.encode_plus(review,
                                           None,
                                           add_special_tokens=True,
                                           max_length=self.max_len,
                                           pad_to_max_length=True,
                                           
        )
        ids= inputs["input_ids"]
        mask= inputs["attention_mask"]
        token_type_ids= inputs["token_type_ids"]
        
        return {
            "ids": torch.tensor(ids,dtype=torch.long),
            "mask": torch.tensor(mask,dtype=torch.long),
            "token_type_ids": torch.tensor(token_type_ids,dtype= torch.long),
            "targets": torch.tensor(self.target[idx],dtype=torch.float)
        }
import torch.nn as nn
class BertBaseUncased(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BertBaseUncased,self).__init__()
        self.bert= transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.bert_drop=nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.out= nn.Linear(768,1)
        
    def forward(self,ids,mask,token_type_ids):
        _,o2= self.bert(ids,attention_mask=mask,token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
        bo= self.bert_drop(o2)
        output= self.out(bo)
        return output
import torch
def loss_fn(outputs,targets):
    return nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(outputs,targets.view(-1,1))

def train_fn(data_loader,model,optimizer,device,scheduler):
    model.train()
    
    for d in data_loader:
        ids=d["ids"]
        token_type_ids= d["token_type_ids"]
        mask= d["mask"]
        targets= d["targets"]
        
        ids=ids.to(device,dtype=torch.long)
        token_type_ids= token_type_ids.to(device,dtype= torch.long)
        mask= mask.to(device,dtype=torch.long)
        targets= targets.to(device,dtype=torch.float)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs= model(ids=ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, mask=mask)
        loss= loss_fn(outputs,targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        
def eval_fn(data_loader,model,device):
    model.eval()
    fin_targets=[]
    fin_outputs=[]
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for d in data_loader:
            ids= d["ids"]
            token_type_ids= d["token_type_ids"]
            mask=d["mask"]
            targets=d["targets"]
            
            ids= ids.to(device,dtype=torch.long)
            mask= mask.to(device,dtype=torch.long)
            targets= targets.to(device,dtype=torch.float)
            token_type_ids= token_type_ids.to(device,dtype=torch.long)
            
            outputs= model(ids=ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, mask=mask)
            
            targets=targets.cpu().detach()
            fin_targets.extend(targets.numpy().tolist())
            outputs=torch.sigmoid(outputs).cpu().detach()
            fin_outputs.extend(outputs.numpy().tolist())
            
    return fin_outputs,fin_targets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import metrics, model_selection
from transformers import AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup

def train():
    df= pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/aamlp-text-data/imdb_folds.csv')
    #df.sentiment= df.sentiment.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=="positive" else "negative")
    df_train,df_valid=model_selection.train_test_split(df,test_size=0.1,random_state=42,shuffle=True,stratify=df.sentiment.values)
    df_train=df_train.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_valid=df_valid.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    train_dataset= BertDataset(review=df_train.review.values,target=df_train.sentiment.values)
    val_dataset= BertDataset(review=df_valid.review.values,target=df_valid.sentiment.values)
    
    train_loader= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=CFG.TRAIN_BS,num_workers=4)
    val_loader= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size=CFG.VAL_BS,num_workers=1)
    
    device= torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model= BertBaseUncased()
    model.to(device)
    
    param_optimizer= list(model.named_parameters())
    no_decay=["bias","LayerNorm.bias","LayerNorm.weight"]
    optimizer_parameters=[{
        "params": [p for n,p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                         "weight_decay":1e-3,
                         },{"params": [p for n,p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                         "weight_decay":0.0,},]
    
    num_train_steps= int(len(df_train)/CFG.TRAIN_BS*CFG.EPOCHS)
    optimizer=AdamW(optimizer_parameters,lr=3e-3)
    scheduler= get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer,
                                              num_warmup_steps=0,
                                              num_training_steps=num_train_steps)
    model=nn.DataParallel(model)
    
    best_accuracy=0
    for epoch in range(CFG.EPOCHS):
        train_fn(train_loader,model,optimizer,device,scheduler)
        outputs,targets= eval_fn(val_loader,model,device)
        outputs= np.array(outputs)>=0.5
        accuracy= metrics.accuracy_score(targets,outputs)
        print(f"Accuracy:{accuracy}")
        if accuracy>best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy=accuracy
            torch.save(model.state_dict(),CFG.MODEL_PATH)
train()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to update in format of Bert outputs due to version change.

To solve this issue the forward pass needs to be modified.

```
class BertBaseUncased(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BertBaseUncased,self).__init__()
        self.bert= transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.bert_drop=nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.out= nn.Linear(768,1)
        
    def forward(self,ids,mask,token_type_ids):
        o2= self.bert(ids,attention_mask=mask,token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
        output_mod= o2.poolee_output
        bo= self.bert_drop(output_mod)
        output= self.out(bo)
        return output
```